# makefile issues multiple definitions

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm learning how to use makefile however after a few hours of research and still being stuck I just can not manage to resolve what is wrong with my makefile:

```
output: main.o module.o
    g++ main.o module.o  -o output
main.o: module.cpp module.h
    g++ -c module.cpp
module.o: module.cpp module.h
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

my `main.cpp` file has `#include "module.cpp"`
my `module.cpp` file has `#include "module.h"`

after attempting to execute my makefile i get lots of  "multiple definitions of" and "undefined references"

help will be highly appreciated

p.s code in codeblocks works flawlessly, that's why i am so confused. i am using mingw32-make

Comment: It is not makefile issue, just do not include *.cpp files and try again/say what the errors are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting "multiple definition errors" becasue you are linking `module.o` and `main.o` together but your `main.cpp` already includes `module.cpp`. Do not include `module.cpp` in `main.cpp` (i.e.: remove the `#include "module.cpp` directive inside `main.cpp`). Since `main.o` won't depend then on `module.cpp`, you should remove that prerequisite from the `main.o` rule as well.

Also, consider using GNU Make's [*automatic variables*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) instead of *hard-coded filenames* and predefined variables (i.e.: `CXX`) instead of hard-coded commands (i.e.: `g++`):

```
output: main.o module.o
    $(CXX) $^  -o $@

main.o: main.cpp module.h
    $(CXX) -c $<

module.o: module.cpp module.h
    $(CXX) -c $<
```

Or even better, rely on the predefined pattern rule for generating `.o` files from `.cpp` files:

```
output: main.o module.o
    $(CXX) $^  -o $@

main.o: module.h
module.o: module.h
```

Note that failing to provide the last two lines will cause `main.o` and `module.o` to be *still up-to-date* (i.e.: not being rebuilt) even though `module.h` changes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to implicit rules in Makefiles, this should be enough:

```
output: main.o module.o
    g++ main.o module.o  -o output
```

The implicit rules allows make to know how to create .o files from .cpp files.

But this could be even simpler:

```
output: main.o module.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ @^
```

$(CXX) is your C++ compiler, usually g++

$@ is an automatic variable of the target (value before the colon)

@^ is an automatic variable of the prerequisites (values after the colon)